# how can use woocommerce add to cart popup?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

i need like this :http://preview.codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-add-to-cart-popup/full_screen_preview/9935308?_ga=2.239113732.647626502.1510046612-167663675.1510046612

i am using mini-cart.php and display popup but it was showing all other items are in cart before added but i need what user click item only in popup[image]